# How to update the database table by removing trailing spaces from one of the columns?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, space

I am trying to write some SQL statement so I can update my entire database table by removing all the spaces from one of its columns.

Here is the database design:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[document_control]    Script Date: 02/06/2012 21:02:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[document_control](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [doc_number] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [doc_title] [nchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [co_num] [int] NULL,
    [co_date] [date] NULL,
    [doc_path] [nchar](256) NULL,
    [doc_revision] [int] NULL,
    [doc_family] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_document_control] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I have lots of spaces in the **[doc_path]** column specifically. I know I can easily use **LTRIM()** function to remove the spaced; however, how can I write a SQL statement so I can update the entire database?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your column type like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[document_control] MODIFY COLUMN [doc_path] [nvarchar](256)
GO
UPDATE [dbo].[document_control] SET 
  [doc_path] = RTRIM([doc_path])
GO
```

And optionally the same for doc title and number.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, it did not work. I still have spaces in the [doc_path] field.

As you can see my script above, the size of the field is 256. After reviewing some records, I realized the size of empty spaces are equal the text entered (e.g. /Documents/Procedures/CR/pdf/CR007.pdf) minus 256 (the total size of the field).

Comment: Yes, but you noticed new type of column - it simply **must work** without doubt